# the_modified_author() returning blank

Tags: columns

I'm attempting to display custom columns that return the last modified date and the author that updated it.

```
function rh_custom_page_columns( $columns ) {
    $columns['last_modified'] = 'Last modified';
    $columns['modified_author'] = 'Modified by';
    return $columns;
}
add_filter('manage_pages_columns','rh_custom_page_columns');

function rh_custom_columns_date_author ( $column_id, $post_id ) {
    switch( $column_id ) {
        case 'last_modified':
            echo get_post_field('post_modified', $post_id);
            break;

        case 'modified_author':
            echo the_modified_author();
            break;
    }
}
add_action( 'manage_pages_custom_column','rh_custom_columns_date_author', 10, 2 );
```

`the_modified_author()` doesn't return any value even though the author exists as a user. I've also tried `get_the_modified_author()` that outputs and empty value too.

How else can I display the author that modified the page (and not the author had originally published it)?

Researching it further, there seems to be a bug? with the function - https://wordpress.org/support/topic/get_the_modified_author-not-working/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`get_the_modified_author` does indeed return an empty value since WordPress does not provide a specific function to retrieve the author of the last modification by default.

An alternative is to use the `wp_get_post_revisions` function to retrieve the revisions of a post and then extract the author of the last revision. Here is the updated code that uses this method:

```
function rh_custom_page_columns( $columns ) {
    $columns['last_modified'] = 'Last modified';
    $columns['modified_author'] = 'Modified by';
    return $columns;
}
add_filter('manage_pages_columns','rh_custom_page_columns');

function rh_custom_columns_date_author ( $column_id, $post_id ) {
    switch( $column_id ) {
        case 'last_modified':
            $revisions = wp_get_post_revisions($post_id);
            if (!empty($revisions)) {
                $latest_revision = reset($revisions);
                echo get_post_field('post_modified', $latest_revision->ID);
            }
            break;

        case 'modified_author':
            $revisions = wp_get_post_revisions($post_id);
            if (!empty($revisions)) {
                $latest_revision = reset($revisions);
                $modified_by = get_userdata($latest_revision->post_author)->display_name;
                echo $modified_by;
            }
            break;
    }
}
add_action( 'manage_pages_custom_column','rh_custom_columns_date_author', 10, 2 );
```

Comment: Note: I’ve tried and tested a the wp_get_post_revisions function on my own since I had the same issue with blank values for get_the_modified_author